# want to remove an object from a sub list

Tags: r

please I want to remove just  20 from score.

```
list1 <- list(numbers=c(1,2),logical=TRUE, strings=c("a","b","c"),score=c(15,20,30))
rm(list=list1[[4]][[2]])
```

> Warning message:
> In rm(list = list1[[4]][[2]]) : object '20' not found

```
list1[[4]][2]
#[1] 20
list1[[4]][2] <- NULL
```

> Error in list1[[4]][2] <- NULL : replacement has length zero

Comment: Use negative indexing: `list1[[4]] <- list1[[4]][-2]`. Or `list1$score <- list1$score[-2]`.

Comment: Thank you @RuiBarradas. I'm a beginner at R and it's great to have helpful people like you.

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 <- list(numbers=c(1,2),logical=TRUE, strings=c("a","b","c"),score=c(15,20,30))
```

Remove 20:

```
correctedscore <- list1$score[-(2:2)]
```

Recreate your list:

```
list1 <- list(numbers=c(1,2),logical=TRUE, strings=c("a","b","c"),correctedscore)
```